# Is possible set an ip address static in a linux image developed in yocto?

Tags: linux, ip, embedded-linux, yocto, static-ip-address

I am using yocto to develop custom linux images and I want to set an ip address for all of my images. It is possible? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `systemd-networkd` or `NetworkManager` as network manager in your Yocto build ?

Comment: I am using systemd-networkd.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To automatically set a static IP in the built image, using `systemd-networkd`:

In your custom layer:

```
meta-custom
    |_ recipes-core
         |_ systemd
              |_ systemd_%.bbappend
         |_ files
              |_ <iface>.link
              |_ <iface>.network
```

For `<iface>` you have to set the interface to be configured by `systemd-networkd`, for example `eth0`, `wlan0`, ...

- **systemd_%.bbappend**

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " networkd resolved"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

MY_INTERFACE = "<iface>"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://${MY_INTERFACE}.network \
    file://${MY_INTERFACE}.link \
"

FILES_${PN} += " \
    ${sysconfdir}/systemd/network/${MY_INTERFACE}.network \
    ${sysconfdir}/systemd/network/${MY_INTERFACE}.link \
"

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/${MY_INTERFACE}.network ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/${MY_INTERFACE}.link ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/
}
```

Also, edit `${MY_INTERFACE}` to same `<iface>`.

**Details**:

- `<iface>.link` is used if you want to set the network device configuration, for example a custom MAC address, for more info check this [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)

Example:

```
[Match]
Name=<iface>

[Link]
MACAddress=12:34:56:78:90:ab
```

- `<iface>.network` used to set the network configuration, for more info check this [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

For a static IP address, here is an example:

```
[Match]
Name=<iface>

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.0.10/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=192.168.0.1
```

**NOTE**

Do not forget to edit `<iface>` in all places (recipe, .link, .network files) according to your desired interface.

Comment: FYI, I had to put the "files" folder into the "systemd" folder in my layer (rather than at the same level as the answer shows).

Comment: I also had to change the ".network" name to something like "20-foo.network".